# Promise returning undefined and status pending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I'm adding some functions to an Angular App and here is the thing: I'm trying to use a function that creates a promise to get data from the server, but every time I try to use it, it returns undefined. I've "debugged" with console.log printing my variable with the result of my function as value and it prints *Promise{'pending'}*

Here is the function of the promise and the variable I'm trying to assign.

```
all_allies(text = ''){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const _text = text ? /${text} : ''
  const path = `${this.env.apiPath}/all_allies${_text}`

  this.$http
    .get(path)
    .then(response => {
      const { data } = response
      resolve(data)
      return data;
    })
    .catch(error  => reject(error))
})
```

Variable

```
let allies = this.AliadosFactory.all_allies();
```

As you can see the function and the variable are in different scripts.

I've tried using await reserved word but still doesn't work

Comment: You should see in the `Network` tab what happened to your request launched by `this.$http.get(..)`

Comment: @samb102 Yeah i did, and the server response is 200-OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this method?

```
let allies = await this.AliadosFactory.all_allies();
console.log(allies);
```

or like this?

```
this.AliadosFactory.all_allies().then(allies => console.log(allies);
```

I sure it should work,
Hope this helps.

Have nice day :)

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the first option before and it didn't worked, but the second does! Now, how do i assign the result to my variable created before?

Comment: Hello Nick! You can assign like this.
```let var1;
this.AliadosFactory.all_allies().then(allies => {
var1 = allies;
});
```

Comment: Hello dalisoft!, unfortunately i just tried but it didn't work, after i assign the variable i print it and prints `undefined`, maybe there is another way? I'm a little bit new with Web Apps

Comment: Nick, it not logs immediately because Promise is async microtask, i recommend you google `async/await in js` for understanding better how and why/where it works, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you perform assignment the Promise is not resolved / rejected yet.

There are two simple solutions:

**1. Using then()**

this.AliadosFactory.all_allies().then(result => console.log(result));

**2. Using async/await**

(note that you need an async method in your class)

```
async foo() {
let allies = await this.AliadosFactory.all_allies();
console.log(allies);
}
```

Also in `all_allies()` you don't need to return the value after calling the `resolve()` method;